# How would I properly print a linked list recursively in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, linked-list

I've been attempting to print a linked list recursively, and I keep getting an error in the output.

I've coded the following:

```
def recursivePrint(linkedList):
    if linkedList == None:
        return
    print linkedList['data'], recursivePrint(linkedList['next'])
```

And it gives an output of:

```
2 7 1 3 10   None
None
None
None
None
None
```

I don't know what exactly I should be doing here, because this should be pretty easy to do. I also need to be able to print the list in reverse, and I figured I'd do almost the same thing I did in my first function.

I coded this for the reverse:

```
def reversePrint(linkedList):
    if linkedList == None:
        return
    print reversePrint(linkedList['next']), linkedList['data']
```

And got an output of:

```
None  
None 10
None 3
None 1
None 7
None 2
```

I think something may have gone wrong in either the if statement, or the recursive step. What should I be doing differently?

Comment: You are printing the return value of `recursivePrint`. `recursivePrint` returns `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print the head of the list, and then call `recursivePrint` on the tail. Your problem right now is that you're printing the return value of `recursivePrint` which is `None`.

```
def recursivePrint(linkedList):
    if linkedList == None:
        return
    print linkedList['data']
    recursivePrint(linkedList['next'])
```

Comment: I would assume that to print it in reverse, I'd have to call reversePrint before the print statement?

Comment: @LamarrL Yes that should do it.